# Automatic variable not expanding properly in Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I am using the following code:

```
HELLO_WORLD=hello

$(HELLO_WORLD): $(addsuffix .c,$@)
        gcc $< -o $@
```

However, when I run the code, I receive the following error, implying that $< is not evaluating to anything:

```
gcc  -o hello
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

When I use the following code...

```
HELLO_WORLD=hello

$(HELLO_WORLD): $(addsuffix .c,$@)
        gcc $(addsuffix .c,$@) -o $@
```

...the Makefile evaluates to the following command...

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

...which is precisely what I would like. However, I do not want to use addsuffix twice. I would like to use $< in the event that I change the prerequisite. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) please. Especially the third paragraph.

Comment: Ahh, so if I understand correctly, automatic variables are only defined in the recipe. So, in the prerequisite, $@ is not defined. Because $< will refer to an expression that depends on $@, which does not exist, $< will therefore not exist as well. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. The answer below is explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the expansion of `$<` in the recipe. The problem is the expansion of `$@` in the prerequisite list.

Automatic variables, such as `$@`, are only defined in the recipe, not in the target or prerequisite lists. This is highlighted in the [GNU Make manual section on automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

> A common mistake is attempting to use `$@` within the prerequisites list; this will not work.

The fact that `hello.c` is not actually in the prerequisite list does not prevent you from invoking `make hello`. It just means that `make hello` will always invoke the compiler, even if `hello.c` has not been modified. But it does mean the `$<` will be as empty as the computed prerequisite list.

GNU make does have a feature to let you do a second expansion of prerequisites; this is explained in the manual. But the simpler solution is to simply not rely on `$@` in the prerequisite list. If you're trying to create your own generic C compile recipe, use a pattern rule for object file (`.o`) targets. For the final executable, list all the prerequisites for the final executable (which will almost certainly be more than one file).

Typically this is done using separate variable with names like `SRCS` and `OBJS` (or `SOURCES` and `OBJECTS` if you don't mind typing vowels). Normally you make the object files prerequisites for the final executable (which will be a link operation), since each individual source file will have its own header prerequisites.

Comment: It looks like if you add "SECONDARYEXPANSION:" above the $(HELLO_WORLD) target and use $$@ instead of $@ in the prerequisite it works. Is there anything wrong with this approach that makes pattern rules preferable?

Comment: Yes, @RomanParise: it is a non-portable GNUism, though I guess you're already well along that road.  It's also harder to read and somewhat surprising to those unfamiliar with it.  A more common approach would be to create a separate variable for the source list.  That especially makes sense as soon as you have more than one source contributing to the binary.

Comment: Alright, I'll write up a comprehensive answer to this. +1! Thanks!

Comment: *"A common mistake ..."* - If users are chronically suffering the same problem, then there's a usability bug in Make. It is absurd users are asked to change their behavior for decades when the tool should be updated to fix the usability problem. That the problem has not been fixed points to an engineering problem: developers are allowed to drive requirements. It always ends poorly.

Comment: @jww: fair point but I think you should direct it at someone who participates in GNU Make development. There's no reason to believe that anyone in that set will read this comment thread, and even if they did this would not be an appropriate place for them to respond. I believe GNU make's mailing lists are still active.

Comment: @rici - Anyone have a link to where you can escalate this to the GNU make dev community? I'll link this post and see if we can make a real change in this world XD.

Comment: @roman: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/ See the "Getting Involved" section towards the bottom for mailing lists and other pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is automatic variables are only defined in the recipe. So, in the prerequisite, $@ is not defined. Because $< will refer to an expression that depends on $@, which does not exist, $< will therefore not exist as well.

So, there are really two ways to resolve the issue. The first way is a bit clunky, but you can use secondary expansions. This essentially allows us to do what we want without adding much code...

```
HELLO_WORLD=hello

SECONDEXPANSION:
$(HELLO_WORLD): $(addsuffix .c,$$@)
        gcc $< -o $@
```

The more proper way to do this involves restructuring the Makefile and using pattern rules. This gives us a generic recipe for building any C file. With the following Makefile, we can either run "make" or "make hello" to build the executable.

```
HELLO_WORLD=hello

all:
        $(MAKE) $(HELLO_WORLD)

%: %.c
        gcc $< -o $@
```

Comment: It's actually `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, not `SECONDARYEXPANSION:`. You can read about it from the official docs at this link. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html